# Message.Show is not working when webpage is published

Tags: c#, asp.net, messagebox

I created a ASP.NET project in which I am using MessageBox.Show to show the user if there is an error or something else. But when I published it, it is giving me this err:

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.

Dont know what it means? What the turnaround of it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MessageBox` is for use within windows (as opposed to web) applications. It would attempt to open a message box on the server. This is not allowed so that application errors.

To show a message on the client you would need to use JavaScript - such as `alert("message")`. You can add styling using something like [jQueryUI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void ShowMSG(string msg,object objPage)
{
    string sj = "<script>" +
        " alert('" + msg + "')" +
        " </script>";       
    System.Web.UI.Page pg = (System.Web.UI.Page)objPage;
    pg.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(objPage.GetType(), "onload", sj);
}
//where object is the page object
```

Answer (score 0):

MessageBox is only used in Windows Forms applications.

Did you mean to issue a JavaScript:alert() to the browser?

Comment: Try this instead: http://archive.devnewz.com/devnewz-3-20061129JavaScriptAlertShowmessagefromASPNETCodebehind.html

Answer (score 0):

use this function in code behind and just call MessageBox("your msg") whenever you need to display message. the function is :

```
private void MessageBox(string msg)
    {

        Page.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(
         "<script language='javascript'>window.location='url of page if you want to redirect.aspx'; window.alert('" + msg.Replace("'", "\\'") + "') </script>"));
        //Response.Write("<script language='Javascript'> window.location='epurchaseorder.aspx'; window.close();</script>");

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't write Messagebox.Show only.....

Try

```
System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox.Show("Your Message");
```